# Resolving template and const volatile type

Tags: c++, templates

I found a following problem, when writing a template, so I have got two templates:

First one is pretty simple, It just `typedefs` given type. It works just fine.

```
template <typename T>
struct myType{
    typedef T type;
};
```

Now I have got a little bit different template and it's as follows:

```
struct None{};

template <typename T1=None,typename T2=None>
struct myTypes;

struct None{};
template <typename T1,typename T2>
struct myTypes<T1(T2)>{
    typedef T1 type1;
    typedef T2 type2;
};
```

So now I would like to test them, and sample test case breaks as follows (using `boost::is_same`)

```
std::cout << is_same<myType<volatile double>::type,volatile double>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << is_same<myTypes<int(volatile double)>::type2, volatile double>::value << std::endl;
```

And suprisngly first test passes and prints '1', and another prints '0'. However when I check it's type with `typeid()` it says it's double for both `volatile` and `non-volatile doubles`

Why is this happening? I do not understand. How can I fix this, so that test case works properly?

Comment: See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for a very detailed description of template deduction, which also will tell you that [CV-qualifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) are ignored..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top level cv-qualifiers are ignored on function parameters.

The following declarations are equivalent (i.e. these are redeclarations of the same function, not an overload set):

```
void f(int i);
void f(const int i);
void f(const volatile int i);
void f(volatile int i);
```

The reason is that a top-level cv-qualifier refers to the **copied** parameter, so it only makes sense potentially in a function definition and has no effect in a function declaration and the type of the function.

Do note that non-top-level cv-qualifiers are not ignored. The following is a set of overloaded functions, not redeclaration of the same function:

```
  void f(int& i);
  void f(const int& i);
  void f(volatile int& i);
```